# Equivalence of digital logic expressions

Tags: logic

Prove that the following three expressions are equivalent

```
     1. if x then y else z
     2. if y then x or z else z > x
     3. if z then x≤y else x∧y
```

Ask for some pointers where to start or at least a link to read about

Comment: Are these boolean values? If so what does `z > x` mean?

Comment: @PaulBoddington  it is binary logic. It probably has something to do with multiplexers

Comment: This is not a programming question...

Comment: To learn more, look for an "introduction to boolean algebra" online. Stack Overflow is not an ideal format to study the topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward approach is to prove equivalence by exhaustively writing down all possible states in a truth table. (It helps that only three boolean variables are involved ;-)

```
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
| x | y | z | if x then y else z | if y then x v z else z > x | if z then x ≤ y else x ∧ y
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 0 |               0    |                0 > 0 = 0   |              0 ∧ 0  = 0
| 0 | 0 | 1 |               1    |                1 > 0 = 1   | 0 <= 0 = 1
| 0 | 1 | 0 |               0    |  0 v 0 = 0                 |              0 ∧ 1  = 0
| 0 | 1 | 1 |               1    |  0 v 1 = 1                 | 0 <= 1 = 1
| 1 | 0 | 0 |   0                |                0 > 1 = 0   |              1 ∧ 0  = 0
| 1 | 0 | 1 |   0                |                1 > 1 = 0   | 1 <= 0 = 0
| 1 | 1 | 0 |   1                |  1 v 0 = 1                 |              1 ∧ 1  = 1
| 1 | 1 | 1 |   1                |  1 v 1 = 1                 | 1 <= 1 = 1
+---+---+---+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
```

Notice how all three functions have the same result for all possible combinations of (x,y,z).

Alternatively, a direct proof is also possible.

First some notation:

```
x + y       x or y
xy          x and y
x'          not(x)
x = 0       x is false
x = 1       x is true
```

And some observations:

- `if x then y else z` is equivalent to `xy + x'z`.
- `z > x` is equivalent to `x'z` (since `z > x` is true iff z is true and x is false.)
- `x ≤ y` is equivalent to `x' + y`

So, to prove one of the equivalences from the question:

```
if y then x + z else z > x
= y(x + z) + y'(z > x)                (if-then-else)
= y(x + z) + y'(x'z)                  (z > x)
= xy + yz + x'y'z                     (distributivity, commutativity)
= xy(z + z') + (x + x')yz + x'y'z     (x + x' = z + z' = 1, and and-ing with 1 has no effect)
= xyz + xyz' + xyz + x'yz + x'y'z
= xyz + xyz'       + x'yz + x'y'z     (xyz + xyz = xyz, or-ing with itself has no effect)
= xy(z + z') + x'z(y + y')            (regroup terms)
= xy + x'z                            (z + z' = y + y' = 1)
= if x then y else z
```

And similarly for the other equivalence in the question.